# Problems with the responsive navigation menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with my navigation menu... it works great on desktops and notebooks, but not on mobile devices.

So, someone can help-me?

Here is the following code for the menu in Desktops/Notebooks screens:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /*
  / nav
  */
  nav {
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    border-bottom: 5px solid white;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Decker';
  }
  nav:after {
    content: '';
    height: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    background: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -15px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  nav a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .nav__cat {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    padding-bottom: .6em;
  }

  .nav__li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 .5em;
  }
  .nav__li:last-child a:before {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav__li:hover > a {
    background: #b42024;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .nav__li:hover > a:after {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav__li:hover .sub__category {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .nav__li > a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 25.6px 0.6em 0.7em 0.6em;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1;
  }
  .nav__li > a:before {
    content: "|";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -10px;
    top: 25.6px;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-4%);
            transform: translateY(-4%);
    line-height: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
  }
  .nav__li > a:after {
    display: none;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8px;
    background: #fac312;
    z-index: 2;
  }

  .sub__category {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .sub__category {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    min-width: 160px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
    margin: 0 .5em;
    padding-top: 23px;
    -webkit-transition: all .12s linear;
    transition: all .12s linear;
  }

  .sub__li {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 2px #000 solid;
    background: #b42024;
  }

  .sub__link {
    padding: .7em 1em;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .sub__link:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  nav li a.active {
    background: #b42024;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  nav li a.active:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8px;
    background: #fac312;
    z-index: 2;
  }

  .sub__li a.active-sub {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

input#control-nav {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
    <header>
        ...
        ...
        ...
    </header>
    
    <input type="checkbox" id="control-nav" />
  <label for="control-nav" class="control-nav"></label>
  <label for="control-nav" class="control-nav-close"></label>
    
    <nav>
    <ul class="nav__cat">
     <li class="nav__li">
      <a href="" class="active">Home</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav__li">
      <a href="#">Sobre a Gente</a>
      <ul class="sub__category">
       <li class="sub__li">
        <a href="#" class="sub__link">Sub-page</a>
       </li>
       <li class="sub__li">
        <a href="#" class="sub__link">Other sub-page</a>
       </li>
       <li class="sub__li">
        <a href="#" class="sub__link">Another sub-page</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="nav__li">
      <a href="#">How find us</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav__li">
      <a href="#">Contact us</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
      </nav>
```

I try to transform this menu in Responsive... and i get this:

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
 
 .control-nav { /* label icon */
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border: solid #333;
    border-width: 3px 0;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .control-nav:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 3px;
    background: #333;
  }

  .control-nav-close {
    position: fixed; /* label layer */
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
    -webkit-transform: translate(100%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(100%, 0);
    transform: translate(100%, 0);
  }

  /* checked nav */
  input#control-nav {
    visibility: visible;
  }

  input#control-nav:focus ~ .control-nav {
    border-color: #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  }

  input#control-nav:focus ~ .control-nav:before {
    background: #000;
  }

  input#control-nav:checked ~ nav,
  input#control-nav:checked ~ .control-nav-close {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
 
 /*
 / nav
 */
 nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 250px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
  overflow-x: auto;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
  -webkit-transform: translate(100%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(100%, 0);
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
 }
 
 nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background: #1c1c1c;
  padding: 5px 0;
 }
 
 nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  line-height: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #383838;
 }
 
 nav li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: none;
 }
 
 nav li a:hover,
 nav li a:focus {
  color: #1c1c1c;
  background: #ccc;
 }
 
 
}
```

```html
    <header>
        ...
        ...
        ...
    </header>
    
    <input type="checkbox" id="control-nav" />
  <label for="control-nav" class="control-nav"></label>
  <label for="control-nav" class="control-nav-close"></label>
    
    <nav>
    <ul class="nav__cat">
     <li class="nav__li">
      <a href="" class="active">Home</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav__li">
      <a href="#">Sobre a Gente</a>
      <ul class="sub__category">
       <li class="sub__li">
        <a href="#" class="sub__link">Sub-page</a>
       </li>
       <li class="sub__li">
        <a href="#" class="sub__link">Other sub-page</a>
       </li>
       <li class="sub__li">
        <a href="#" class="sub__link">Another sub-page</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="nav__li">
      <a href="#">How find us</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav__li">
      <a href="#">Contact us</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
      </nav>
```

I appreciate it the help!

Oh and sorry for my English!, It's not great.

Comment: You need to add one more break point around `500px` or something. In that break point adjust your CSS for menu.

Comment: You don't have any media queries that target those smaller devices. You're going to need something like `max-width: 420px`.

Comment: Be more specific with what you need help with. What's the problem exactly?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @MichaelCoker I do not know how to insert a submenu inside the parent element of it ... I've already managed to make the menu work, however, I can not include the submenus